# When an iBeacon wakes an iOS app, will the WiFi radio power up?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

Scenario: Backgrounded iOS app monitoring an iBeacon region.  The device's WiFi radio was powered down by iOS (30 minutes of inactivity).

When the device enters the region of the the iBeacon and the app wakes to handle the location notification, will the WiFi radio power up and connect to an available remembered WiFi network?

Comment: Isn't iBeacon based on Bluetooth, not WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a local notification causes the lock screen to come up.  I last tested this in the past (on iOS 6) and as of that OS version, this did cause a WiFi scan to start.  Assuming this has not changed in subsequent iOS releases, then yes, this would work as you say.

To be clear, though, this is nothing specific to iBeacons -- this is just about the behavior of iOS when it brings up the lock screen due to a local notification.